# Group $G$ with $\vert G \vert =60$ and $\vert Z(G)\vert$ is divisible by $4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I recently came across the following problem:

> Suppose $G$ is a group with $\vert G \vert =60$ and $\vert Z(G)\vert$ is divisible by $4$. Show that $G$ is Abelian

**My Try:** By Lagrange's  theorem and the hypothesis $4$ divides $ \vert Z(G)\vert$, $$\vert Z(G)\vert\in \{4,12,20,60\}$$

But the index $[G:Z(G)]$ in any finite group is always cannot be prime, so $\vert Z(G)\vert \neq 12,20$

so   $\vert Z(G)\vert$ is either $4$ or $60$. If the latter holds, then $G=Z(G) $ and we are done. If the former holds, then $G/Z(G)$ has order $15$ and any group of order $15$ is cyclic and so the quotient is cyclic and so $G$ is Abelian

---

Is this argument correct? If not, what I'm doing wrong?

If so, is there any other easy method to approach this?

Comment: You can exclude $4,12$ and $20$ simultaneously, as you're ultimately quoting the same theorem (that $G/Z(G)$ cannot be non-trivial and cyclic).

Comment: Oh Yes!. I agree